# jquery for Cascading Dropdown in MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm working in Asp.net MVC3. I'm using two `DropdownList` which are **Vertical** and **Account**. Based on the selection of Vertical, Account `DropdownList` should get visible and populated with data according to the Vertical selection. How could do this using **JQuery**?

I'm using following code and got the Accountvalues based on the selection of Vartical. What I have to give in success function of Ajax call to make the Account `DropdownList` visible and populated with values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#vertical").change(function (e) {
        var vertical = $("#vertical").val();
        cascadingdropdown(vertical);
    });
});


function cascadingdropdown(vertical) {
    $("#account").empty();
    $("#account").append("<option value='0'></option>");

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Account","Home")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            vertical: vertical
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you returning from Account action in Home controller? Do you need to use data to assign values, maybe you can just assign value from vertical without going to the server.

Comment: From Account Action i'm returning Accountvalues of Corresponding Vertical from server.I need to made the second dropdown visible and populated with the data returned from Account Action.

Comment: try this http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Creating-a-Cascading-Dropdown-in-ASPnet-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are returning json data, than you would do something like this:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON($(data).text());
 for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++){
  listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonData[i].Value + "'>" + jsonData[i].Text + "</option>";
}
$("#account").html(listItems);
$("#account").show();
```

For this to be a complete answer, you need to give an example of data returned from server.
Otherwise this is more or less pseudo code...